# Angular2 drag and drop unusable, but fixed if removing an unrelated part of the template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am using Angular2 to implement drag and drop capabilities. I want to move "windows" that are inside "sessions", and each window has a number of bookmarks on it.

What I see is that when I have a slightly complex structure, let's say 4 sessions each one with 2 windows and each window with 5-10 bookmarks in it, then moving the windows from one session to another is very slow, up to 60seconds waiting (!!)

**Then, if I don't include in the template the bookmarks, everything is snappy.**

My first solution has been to render the bookmarks in a container outside the sessions, i.e. outside the drag&drop directives, and I then move the bookmarks by javascript (typescript) from the outside container to the session-window again when demanded.

The bookmarks are unrelated to the sessions, they are outside. **but still if they are in the template, everything is unusable again.** And if I remove them from the template, then **everything is snappy again**.

Then why is that? How is that they produce this impact? How could I fix it?

EDIT: 
quick&dirty plunker, try to move the "title" sections and you will wait seconds
https://plnkr.co/edit/VyKo3BIvThn1BbMt3lCv?p=preview

And the second plunker without the bookmarks loaded (in `app.html`), it is snappy
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEG9glXlgzVvapyOwvnE?p=preview

Part of the template

```
<section id="current_bookmarks">
    <div *ngFor="let session_window_name of session_keys;" 
        [bookmark_draggable_target]="{event_type:'moving_sessions',zone:session_window_name}" 
        (drop_here)="onDrop($event)">
        <div class="session_window_name">
            <div class="session_window_name_title"><input class="input_session_names title" [id]="sessions[session_window_name].name+'_input'" type="text" value="{{sessions[session_window_name].title}}"></div>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let window_name of sessions[session_window_name].windows_keys; let i = index;" 
            [bookmark_draggable]="{event_type:'moving_sessions',id:session_window_name+'_'+sessions[session_window_name].windows[window_name].id}">
            <session [index]="i" [from]="'stored'" [session]="session_window_name" [window]="sessions[session_window_name].windows[window_name]"></session>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And if the part below is removed (within the same template), then the problem is fixed. BUT, there's no `bookmark_draggable` or `bookmark_draggable_target` directives here (!)

```
<section id="bookmarks_pool">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let session_window_name of session_keys;">
        <div *ngFor="let window_name of sessions[session_window_name].windows_keys; let i = index;">
            <div *ngFor="let bookmark of sessions[session_window_name].windows[window_name].bookmarks; let i = index;" >
                <div>
                    <span class="material-icons list_shown" (click)="bookmark_delete(session_window_name+'_'+sessions[session_window_name].windows[window_name].id+'_'+i+'_bookmark')">label</span>
                    <span class="material-icons clear_hidden" (click)="bookmark_delete(session_window_name+'_'+sessions[session_window_name].windows[window_name].id+'_'+i+'_bookmark')">clear</span>
                    <a target="_blank" [href]="sanitize(bookmark.url)">{{bookmark.url}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

</section>
```

The directives

```
import { Output, EventEmitter, Input, HostListener, Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

export interface DropTargetOptions {
    zone?: any;
    id?: any;
    event_type?:any;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[bookmark_draggable_target]'
})

export class DropTargetDirective {
    private options: DropTargetOptions = {};

    @Input() set bookmark_draggable_target(options: DropTargetOptions) {
        if (options)
            this.options = options;
    }

    @Output('drop_here') drop = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(ev:any) {
        const {zone={},id={},event_type='default_event'} = this.options;
        if (ev.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('application/x-$'+event_type) >= 0)
            ev.preventDefault();
        else
            console.log(ev.dataTransfer.types)
    }

    @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) onDrop(ev:any) {
console.log('what')
        const {zone={},event_type='default_event'} = this.options;
        const info = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData('application/x-$'+event_type));
        this.drop.next({info,zone});
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Input, HostListener, Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

export interface DraggableOptions {
    id?: any; // ? is for optional
    event_type?:any;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[bookmark_draggable]'
})

export class DraggableDirective {
    private options: DraggableOptions = {};

    @HostBinding('draggable') get draggable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Input() set bookmark_draggable(options: DraggableOptions) {
        if (options)
            this.options = options;
    }

    @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event']) onDragStart(event:any) {
        const {id={}, event_type='default_event'} = this.options;
//      event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.getElementById(id),0,0);
        event.dataTransfer.setData('application/x-$'+event_type, JSON.stringify(this.options));
    }

}
```

EDIT: tab.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
//      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
//      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
//      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
//      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
//      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
//      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
//      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
//      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
//      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
//      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'

      // chrome extension changes
      '@angular/core': 'lib/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'lib/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'lib/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'lib/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'lib/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'lib/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'lib/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'lib/forms.umd.js',

      'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'lib/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './tabs.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);

System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

EDIT: package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.12",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10"
  },
```

Comment: Can you create full demo? How does session component look like?

Comment: @yurzui I've just added a plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Instead of using `sanitize` function i would use custom pure pipe.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the input value while your `sanitize` function is executed during each change detection cycle.

```
[href]="bookmark.url | safe">
<img class="bookmark_favicon" [src]="('chrome://favicon/'+bookmark.url) | safe"
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/7Qnxsh2a4OIODgQX13u0?p=preview

2) When you deal with sorting and moving items i would also use `trackBy` within `ngFor`

3) Another improvement is subscribing to `dragover` event outside angular zone:

**drop-target.directive.ts**

```
listener: Function;

constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.listener = this.renderer.listen(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'dragover', (ev) => {
        const { zone = {}, id = {}, event_type = 'default_event' } = this.options; // the one defined in "bookmark_draggable_target"
        if (ev.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('application/x-$' + event_type) >= 0) // the one sent in the event
            ev.preventDefault();
        else
            console.log(ev.dataTransfer.types)
    });
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.listener();
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/NXOZUk8L5bM2k6ceQUpx?p=preview

or

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
...
zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  this.subscription = Observable.fromEvent(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'dragover').subscribe((ev: any) => {
    const { zone = {}, id = {}, event_type = 'default_event' } = this.options; // the one defined in "bookmark_draggable_target"
    if (ev.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('application/x-$' + event_type) >= 0) // the one sent in the event
      ev.preventDefault();
    else
      console.log(ev.dataTransfer.types)
  });
})

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/HrmPPHJ63WjYC1SHNUQp?p=preview

4) Next step is having component that will render bookmarks and have `OnPush` change detection strategy

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! However, I'm trying to implement the Renderer2 improvement, but I don't know why, when using this in a Chrome extension the `import Renderer2 from '@angular/core';` in `drop-target.directive.ts` fails: `Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for DropTargetDirective`. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I've added the config file at the end of the question

Comment: Try Renderer instead of Renderer2. Renderer2 was introduced in v4. Or you can use `Observable.fromEvent`. I will update answer

Comment: It is something with the packages, since if I retrieve the files from https://unpkg.com/ as in plunker I don't get any error. I add to the question my package.json, can you spot any error there?

Comment: Update typescript as well

Comment: If your code is located in `lib/core.umd.js` so maybe you forgot to run some gulp task

Comment: It is already at 2.2.2, I've run npm updated, and then I've copied from the node_modules folder the script to `/lib`. Unless the update doesn't occur in node_modules, I don't know what's going on

Comment: Yes, you were right, I was copying files with a script, and I wasn't running the right script (!), so now it works! Thanks a lot, I'll do a couple more of tests and I'll then accept your answer, thanks a lot again!